# Datatables Translation not working

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm struggling with [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) translations. As far as I understand the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.url), it should load the language file via Ajax.

I don't see an HTTP request to the file `/static/assets/js/datatables_de.json` at all (not in Chrome's developer toolbar nor on the server). What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hitstable = $('#hitstable').DataTable({
        "ajax": '/customer/ajax_get_hits',
        "stateSave": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { aTargets: [0], bSortable: false },
            { aTargets: [1], bSortable: true },
            { aTargets: [2], bSortable: true },
            { aTargets: [3], bSortable: true },
            { aTargets: [4], bSortable: true },
            { aTargets: [5], bSortable: true },
            { aTargets: [6], bSortable: true },
            { aTargets: [7], bSortable: true },
            { aTargets: [8], bSortable: false },
        ],
        "bServerSide": true,
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        "oLanguage": {
            sProcessing: '<img src="/static/assets/img/loading.gif">'
        },
        "language": {
            "url": "/static/assets/js/datatables_de.json"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you refering to local files? https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/comment/88594/#Comment_88594

Comment: You might allready know this, but you could just add the json directly like this: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html 
or reference a external url from here: http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/i18n/

Comment: No, I am not referring to local files. Just like in the example. Also, this doesn't work:

"language": {
  "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
}

Comment: Adding the JSON directly doesn't work too.

Comment: Try to change to "dataTable" and change the end of the file to "de_de.lang".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think I've figured it out.

It seems that oLanguage and language is not compatible. oLanguage is considered legacy, and just by adding it to the configuration it seems like it overrides the language field.

sProcessing is included in the language files, so you should not need to add it to the configuration.

Try and remove the oLanguage:
https://jsfiddle.net/fzg38jta/1/

or by adding the language in the oLanguage instead:

```
{
    "sProcessing":   "Próiseáil...",
    "sLengthMenu":   "Taispeáin iontrálacha _MENU_",
    "sZeroRecords":  "Gan aon taifead meaitseáil aimsithe",
    "sInfo":         "_START_ Showing a _END_ na n-iontrálacha  _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty":    "Showing 0-0 na n-iontrálacha  0",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(scagtha ó _MAX_ iontrálacha iomlán)",
    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
    "sSearch":       "Cuardaigh:",
    "sUrl":          "",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "An Chéad",
        "sPrevious": "Roimhe Seo",
        "sNext":     "Ar Aghaidh",
        "sLast":     "Last"
    }
}
```